# Access dynamically created local dom on ready

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to access .city elements on ready through `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("#office-cities-acc .city");` But it isn't returning anything. I'm thinking that it is because those elements are created through dom-repeat, dynamically. Is it so? What are the ways to access them?

```
    <template> 
       <iron-ajax
        auto url="@{Office.getOffices}" params='{"alt":"json", "q":"polymer"}'
        handle-as="json" last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

    ....
            <div class="office-cities-list">
                <div class="panel-group" id="office-cities-acc">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.officesRegions]]"
                        as="region">
                            <template is="dom-if" if= "{{checkRegionType(region.type)}}">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                             ...
                        </div>
                        <div id="{{computeUrl(region.regionsId)}}"
                            class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul>
                                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.officesCities]]"
                                        as="city">
                                        <template is = "dom-if" if="{{checkCityRegion(region.regionsId,city.regionsId)}}">
                                    <li class="city"><a href="#" 
                                        data-city-name$={{getNameByLang(city)}}>{{getNameByLang(city)}}</a></li>
                                    </template></template>....

</template>
```

Comment: What do you want to try to achieve ? 

I guess you are building a list of cities from the response of an ajax call. 
There is no way to do this in the `ready` callback because the `ready` callback is called when you create your custom element. You could add an `observer` for the `ajaxResponse` property and try to access them there.